# Get text from html element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, lib

I want to log in Robot framework log file the message in the paragraph inside the form "Summary text". However this `paragraph` doesn't have an id neither class. In this case how can I get that text to log it on Robot Framework?

```
    <div id="results">
                    
       <h2>Results</h2>
     
       <form id="form_results" method="POST" >
    
        <p>Summary text</p>
        ....
       </form>
    ...
    </div>
```

I was trying like this "`Log  id: form_results:p`", but it doesn't work:

```
*** Keywords ***
Log message
    Log  id:form_results:p
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your approach - the locator of the element, and the way you get its text; let's start with the latter as it's easier.

RF is an "action" based framework - you instruct it to do some action, passing arguments to control it. One such action/keyword is the `Log` one - it'll log a message.
You called it, and passed "id:form_results:p" - now, why would it do anything different from logging that string? For you, it's a locator, and you might expect "it should log the text of the element, because this is obviously a locator" - but, how would it know this is what you intent, just because it looks like a locator? In different context it may not be desired to do that; so the keyword does the only action it is designed for - to log whatever string or variable is passed.

To do what you want, get the text and then log it, you have to do those two actions - first get the text and assign to a var:

```
${text}=    Get Text    ${my locator}
```

, and then log the value of the var:

```
Log    ${text}
```

On to the other issue - the locator. What you have specified -  id:form_results:p - is not a valid one; it is described as "an element with id attribute equal to form_result:p", while you probably meant "an element with id attribute equal to form_result, and then its child p".
Here are 3 different locators strategies to accomplish that:

```
css:form#form_result p    # a css locator
xpath://form[@id="form_result"]   # an xpath one
id:form_result >> name:p   # mixing two locator strategies, first an id one, then name
```

Use any of the options in place of `${my locator}` above, and you should be fine.